# display a table within a table on a button click in angular 7

Tags: html, django, angular7

I am quite new to angular and web development  and i am working with tables getting data from django PostgreSQL db to the front-end in form of tables. So, i need to have an details button in each row, clicking on which a new table is shown after that row. I am following the https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples 
of the expandable rows but i am not able to get desired results. 
i need to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/6Texj/ but in angualar7.

I've created the buttons (expand_more mat icon)in the rows and a function(on-click event)which is getting the response from django view, what is left is to display the filtered data in details table.

Is it possible to get the response in the **description** field as shown in the example below of angular material table, as the description is forming the expanded part of the table. 
Or i should follow a different approach altogether. I am very new to web development kindly ignore my mistakes.

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {
    position: 1,
    name: 'Hydrogen',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H',
    description: `Hydrogen is a chemical element with symbol H and atomic number 1. With a standard
        atomic weight of 1.008, hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table.`
  }